# What happens when a user closes window to the uploaded files (JSF)

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I am wondering what happens in this specific case:

1. The user opens a JSF page and uploads some files (via `<p:fileUpload>`).
   The file is stored now in a temporary folder.
2. Then the user submits the form, where the temporary saved files are transferred to the fileserver.
3. During this transfer, the user closes the window.

Can I do a kind of a "rollback" for the files? What happens when the user closes the windows during the file transfer in the background ?

Comment: You can easily test this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this by the means of PHP only, but I think JSF behaves the same.

If the user closes the window **during** the transfer, the upload will be cancelled, because it is incomplete. The $_FILES variable will contain a specific error message and the temp file is **not** available.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you know how long thr temp files are stored? Till the storage is full or after a specific time?

Comment: PHP removes them after script termination.

Comment: You may do a test by yourself. Increase the maximum upload size, i.e. in the .htaccess. Then do a large file upload and terminate it before it ends. Watch the temp directory.

Comment: OP doesn't describe close of window during file upload process itself, but during the "confirmation" submit whereby the server transfers the already uploaded and obtained files from temp dir to the final destination dir.